# Rails / CanCan allowing update of a single attribute for CarrierWave attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cancan

In my Rails app I have a `Client` model which `has_many :client_attachments`. I want non-admin users to be able to create attachments, but I don't want them to update other attributes for `Client`.

I'm using `CanCan` for role authorization and `CarrierWave` for attachments.

Currently I'm doing:

In `models/client.rb`:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_attachments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In `models/client_attachment.rb`:

```
class ClientAttachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, ClientAttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :client
end
```

In `ability.rb`:

```
can [:update], Client
can [:create, :update, :destroy], ClientAttachment, :user_id => user.id
```

In `clients_controller.rb`:

```
private
  def client_params
    if current_user.admin?
        params.require(:client).permit(:name, :address, :etc, 
          client_attachments_attributes: [:id, :client_id, :file, :user_id])
    elsif current_user.user?
        params.require(:client).permit(client_attachments_attributes: [:id, :client_id, :file, :user_id])
    end
  end
```

So it is actually the client controller which lets non-admin users update only the attachment out of all of the client's attributes.

This approach is bothering me because it doesn't play well with the views. Where I have `<% if can? :edit, Client %>` it will look like for the non-admin user as if he could edit the client, when in fact he can only edit attachments.

Any ideas on a better approach to this?

Comment: one of the great things about cancan is you can(can) make permissions for any action on the object,  you could create a new "action" which is specific to uploading the attachment `:upload_attachment`, give the admin permission to both `upload_attachment` and `edit` while the non admin can only `upload_attachment`.  You would have to use custom authorize action on the controller, but it can be done.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'm trying to `authorize! :upload_attachment, @client if params[:client_attachments]` but it's not working, probably because `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of the controller overrides it. Any tips?

Comment: you would need to skip the authorize for the controller action and call `authorize!` for both `:upload_attachment` and `:edit` in the controller action.  you can do `skip_authorize_resource only: :edit` for this